# Inexplicable delay in receiving data via Unix socket using Python code

Tags: python, sockets, unix-socket

I have the following setup: a few dozen Python modules running which collect data, they send these data to an aggregator which is a Golang module, using a Unix socket connection (one file for everybody).

The aggregator crunches numbers and sends the aggregated data back to the Python modules on the same socket connection.

It does work. However, there's an ever increasing delay in between the sending of packets from the aggregator and the receipt of said packets. In a half an hour it can get up to a minute long delay.

I tried logging everything and I saw that there's no delays on the sending side (from the aggregator). But when it's received in the Python modules the packets arrive with an ever increasing delay. It happens even if the Python module only uses the socket connection for listening, and it's doing nothing else but waits for data to come in on the socket connection.

The setup is quite complex but here are the main portions of the code which are relevant:

```py
# creation of the socket
import socket
import asyncio
#...
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
sock= Socket(socket.AF_UNIX)
sock.setblocking(False)
await loop.sock_connect(sock, '/tmp/mysock')
```

```py
# receipt of the packages
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
  # ...
  print("DBG: before socket read @",datetime.now().timestamp())
  async with asyncio.timeout(Timeout):
    newFrag=await loop.sock_recv(sock, BUFFSIZE)
  print("DBG: after socket read @",datetime.now().timestamp())
  # ...
```

For example here's some lines from the logs where two packets were sent with only 1 millisecond apart but they arrived 0.65 seconds apart.

```
...
DBG: after socket read @ 1695743800.925668 [1]
Received secData: (False, {'Ts': 1695743796, 'Main': 354.76, 'Secondary': 33678.9, 'SendTs': 1695743797.713 [2] })
DBG: before socket read @ 1695743800.926059 [3]
DBG: after socket read @ 1695743801.57975 [4]
Received secData: (False, {'Ts': 1695743797, 'Main': 354.76, 'Secondary': 33678.8, 'SendTs': 1695743797.714 [5]})
DBG: before socket read @ 1695743801.585009
...
```

Timestamp [1] and timestamp [2] show that there's already 3.2 sec delay. The difference between [1] and [4] shows that there was a delay of 0.65 sec between getting the two packets. The difference between [2] and [5] shows only 1ms between the sending of the two packets.

The above example from a Python script that did nothing else than listening to incoming packets.

I'm out of ideas as to why this is. I could understand a few hundred ms delay here and there but not the accumulation of the delays. Any clues for the underlying cause would be appreciated.

Comment: at a guess your listener just has a queue waiting for processing ?... it looks like it start processing almost immediately after the after socket read, which makes me think you have a queue of pending messages waiting ... as that queue grows it will take a longer and longer time to get through... maybe you need more than one listener?

Comment: Good guess. But that's not the case. In my test there was no processing done with it, just print it out. As you can see from the log, it took only 1ms to get back to the listening (difference between [1] and [3]) but the listening (`loop.sock_recv()`) took 0.65sec, even though there must have been a packet there ready to be read.

Comment: Have you played around a bit with e. g.  `BUFFSIZE` or tried to use a network socket instead?

Comment: *"...  the main portions of the code which are relevant"* - These minimal code snippets are not sufficient to explain the problem. And they might not even be the relevant ones either but the problem might be somewhere else in your complex setup. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on what you should provide so others can reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I changed the `BUFFSIZE` around which made no difference. The packets are small. Have not tried network socket yet. That will be next thing. Thanks for the tip. I prefer to use Unix Sockets but if it works correctly with a network socket, then I'll take that. I'll let you know.